# .navigationTitle aways creates an autolayout-constraint conflict

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-14.3-defect

**Environment:** Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33) 
Version 12.3 (12C33)

I notice that the **NavigationTitle** breaks the autolayout after updating to Xcode 12.3 RC.

Here's a simple example (revised to modern syntax per comment):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
            }.navigationTitle(Text("Greetings World!"))
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here's what I get upon running this:

```
2020-12-09 11:42:19.994389-0800 UICheck[26092:799713] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170e1c0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac096e0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac06db0'Greetings World!']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170e210 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac06db0'Greetings World!'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x7feb5ac066a0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170ef80 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac096e0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600000d5db20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170efd0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7feb5ac066a0]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600000d5da40'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170ae90 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600000d5da40'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7feb5ae185f0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170f750 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7feb5ae185f0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170b250 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600000d5db20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7feb5ae185f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000170e1c0 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac096e0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7feb5ac06db0'Greetings World!']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

This is the source of the problem:

[image]

I suspect this to be another Apple Bug.  
Being that I'm using the supplied .navigationBarTitle view, how can I fix this?

Comment: Then it is really a 14.3 defect, submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: I just did:  I sent the code with your changes to Apple.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated for Xcode 13**

To solve the LayoutConstraints error on SwiftUI NavigationView, make it conform to this style:

`.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` on Xcode 12

`.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` on Xcode 13

```
struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
        Text("Hello world!")
          .padding()
      }
      .navigationTitle("Greetings World!")
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve the warnings for me, it still occurred.
Turns out `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` needs to be added to the NavigationView, not to a view within it.

Comment: The code is updated for Xcode 13, and fixed for Xcode 12 which do not show the log error in the console.

Comment: With Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15, 15.2 on Simulator iPhone, there are again a lot of Constraints Conflicts. No conflicts on iOS 14 Simulator. Same code as of Jul 26 '21.